# Google sheets appscript - Pipedrive post

Tags: google-apps-script, pipedrive-api

I am getting the error 'Exception: Request failed for https://api.pipedrive.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: {"status":false,"error":"Unknown method ."} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)' when attempting a put/post request to a Pipedrive deal. (Date Field) Below is the function producing the error. I am pretty sure this is something obvious but have not been able to determine the cause on my own. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function Update_pipedrive_Date(dealid, field_name){
  var todays_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "yyyy-MM-dd"); // "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
  var url = 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/' + dealid + '?api_token='+oys_api_key
  var data = {field_name: todays_date};
  var options = {
  'method': 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  return response
}


def update_field(this_dealid, fieldid):
    tday = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    updates = {fieldid: tday}
    resp = requests.put(
        'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/' + str(
            this_dealid) + '?api_token=' + api_key,
        data=json.dumps(updates), headers=headers)
    return resp
```

Comment: About `I have no issues with posting to pipedrive via the api with python.`, can you provide the python script?

Comment: I edited my original post to add the python.. sorry I am not sure how to separate these 2 code blocks on my phone.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided python script, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Your provided python script works fine.
- You want to convert your python script to Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- Your python script requests the PUT method. But your Google Apps Script requests the POST method.
- In the case of `{field_name: todays_date}`, the key is always "field_name".

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var field_name = "###"; // Please set your field_name.
var dealid = "###"; // Please set your dealid.
var oys_api_key = "###"; // Please set your oys_api_key.

var todays_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "yyyy-MM-dd");
var url = 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/' + dealid + '?api_token=' + oys_api_key;
var data = { [field_name]: todays_date };
var options = {
  'method': 'put',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

#### Note:

- I think that the request of this Google Apps Script is the same as your python script. But if this script occurs an error, please confirm your variables of `field_name`, `dealid`, `oys_api_key` again. Even when these variables are the valid values, when an error occurs, I'm worried that the URL might not be able to be accessed from the Google side.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Yep, that worked. Not sure if was the 'put' or the extra brackets around field name, but regardless, it worked, appreciate your help!

Comment: @BG1983 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.